# YUI3 JavaScript: get CSS for placeholder text

Tags: javascript, css, html, placeholder, yui3

I'm writing some JavaScript to implement placeholder text in browsers that don't have it.

I've successfully styled the placeholder text in Chrome 9 and Fx 4b11 using the following style rules:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #969696 !important; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #969696 !important; }
```

Now I want my JavaScript to retrieve this data from the stylesheet in browsers that don't understand those rules so I can manually style the placeholder text.

Does anyone know how I can do that in YUI3? I tried:

```
YUI().use('node',function(Y) {
    var phColor = Y.all('::-webkit-input-placeholder').getStyle('color');
});
```

Unfortunately this just returns:
"undefined: not bound to any nodes { _query="input::-webkit-input-placeholder", _nodes=}"

Anyone know how I can do this? Or if it's possible?

Comment: So I realised that the native CSS object in all browsers only shows rules that the browser understands, and therefore finding "::-webkit-input-placeholder" thought unsupporting browsers' object is impossible.
The only way to do this, as far as I can tell, is to parse the CSS directly using something like [JSCSSP](http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/) and then search through the resulting object model for the required CSS rules. I may write a YUI3 module to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't sold on using YUI exclusively (or are willing to harvest the jQuery code from a plugin and convert it to a YUI3 module) this jQuery plugin does exactly what you are trying to do: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin

I've used it in a production environment and it works great even as far back as IE6 :)

Comment: No it doesn't. I've already written the general placeholder replicator code. The bit I want to solve is using `::-webkit-input-placeholder` or `:-moz-placeholder` to style it. This plugin doesn't do that. What it does do is add a `class="placeholder"` to elements with placeholder, so that they can be easily styled, which is a good alternative solution. I'll vote you up as that is helpful, but this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I misunderstood. Hopefully the plugin I linked can offer an acceptable alternative. Ideally it would be nice to style the HTML5 placeholders with only CSS so if you find a solution that allows this I'd be interested to see :)

Comment: I'm accepting this, as I don't think there is a solution and this is the closest I've got to it.